# Concatenate two columns only if both contains string value, not NA value, in R

Tags: r

I googled and I found out the solution for Python and SQL but not for R coding.

I attach an example of a dataframe called df1 in order to be easy to understand.

```
Genus          Species       Genusspecie
Escherichia     coli       Escherichia coli
Campylobacter    NA        NA
Shigella        sonnei     Shigella sonnei
```

If exists NA in df1 is only in the variable column of Specie.

Then I desire that if NA exists in Specie the complete species name (new variable created called Genusspecie) appears NA. If Genus and Specie are both informed, I desire to obtain the completne specie name.

I tried the command paste but then I will need to transform the string cells of dataframe containing NA to a string cell only containing NA without genus information.

```
df1$Genusspecie <- paste(taxa2$Genus, taxa2$Species)
```

Thanks on advance for your help,

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifelse`. If `Species` is `NA`, return `NA`, otherwise `paste` the two columns together.

```r
within(df1, GenusSpecies <- ifelse(is.na(Species), NA, paste(Genus, Species)))
#>           Genus Species     GenusSpecies
#> 1   Escherichia    coli Escherichia coli
#> 2 Campylobacter    <NA>             <NA>
#> 3      Shigella  sonnei  Shigella sonnei
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Genus   = c("Escherichia", "Campylobacter", "Shigella"), 
                  Species = c("coli", NA, "sonnei"))
```

Comment: Many thanks. That worked as desired! I learned now!

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use case for `str_c` from `stringr` package:
Different to `paste` `str_c` returns a `NA` if there is one `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(GenuSpecies = str_c(Genus, Species, sep = " "))
```

```
         Genus Species      GenuSpecies
1   Escherichia    coli Escherichia coli
2 Campylobacter    <NA>             <NA>
3      Shigella  sonnei  Shigella sonnei
```

Comment: Many thanks. That worked as desired! I learned now!